# Обновление QCombobox приводит к рекурсии?

Tags: c++, qt

В общем, хочу сделать так, чтоб при открытии комбобокса происходило его же обновление - обновление списка COM-портов в системе.

```
void MainWindow::updateCOMlist() 
{
    ui->comboBoxCOMport->clear();
    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        ui->comboBoxCOMport->addItem(info.portName());
    }

}
```

Делаю это по сигналу:

```
 connect(ui->comboBoxCOMport,
         SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
         this,
         SLOT(updateCOMlist()));
```

и как я понял происходит такое действие: вначале происходит очищение, потом добавляется первый элемент, что вызывает слот и происходит снова удаление и так далее.

Как можно исправить данную проблему ?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте:

```
void MainWindow::updateCOMlist() {
    ui->comboBoxCOMport->blockSignals(true);

    ui->comboBoxCOMport->clear();
    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        ui->comboBoxCOMport->addItem(info.portName());
    }

    ui->comboBoxCOMport->blockSignals(false);
}
```

---

**PS.**

*Я бы поразбирался с архитектурой, возможно можно сделать по другому, но для вашего примера*

Comment: хм, проблема частично решилась, при попытке смены индекса происходит обновление, но при этом я не могу выбрать индекс, кроме первого и все таки хотелось бы обновлять просто при развертываннии

Comment: Изменив сигнал на SIGNAL(activated(int)), и добавив строку ui->comboBoxCOMport->setCurrentIndex(index);  смог менять индекс

Answer (score 3):

При добавлении новых элементов используйте блокировку сигналов.

```
Combobox->blockSignals(true)
//add actions
Combobox->blockSignals(false)
```

Тогда сигналы от виджета не будут поступать и не будет зацикливания.

Answer (score 1):

Другим вариантом решение может быть переопределение метода void [QComboBox::showPopup()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#showPopup)

```
#include <QComboBox>

class CPortsComboBox : public QComboBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CPortsComboBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~CPortsComboBox();

public:
    virtual void showPopup()
    {
        while (count() > 0) { removeItem(0); }
        addItem("hello");
        addItem("World"):
        QComboBox::showPopup();
    }
};
```

Более трудоёмким решение будет переопределение eventfilter-ов. [В этой теме](https://forum.qt.io/topic/32213/which-signal-is-related-to-click-or-open-qcombobox/2) это обсуждалось.